# Handling data from .csv file generated incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm currently trying to manipulate data from a *.csv file that has been generated incorrectly for the past 2 days. Previously the macro worked fine. The *.csv file contains over 40000 lines of data.
I'm receiving error message:Subscript out of range(on line 4 of the below code) => If I open the just the .csv file into the Dev mode I noticed into the Microsoft Excel Objects(in Project Explorer) I have just an Excel Workbook (called ThisWorkbook without the Sheet1). Have you been into a similar situation and how I'm suppose to refer to the data stored into file such as this?

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=aFileName, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Tab:=True, local:=True

Set wbk_Extraction = ActiveWorkbook

wbk_Extraction.SaveAs wbk_Extraction.Name

Set wsh_Extraction = wbk_Extraction.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: A workbook always has at least one sheet, so if your csv file is opening as a zero-sheet workbook then something is really wrong with that csv

Comment: Your parameters indicate that both tab _and_ comma is the delimiter. I've no idea what the issue is from your explanation but the first thing to do is open it in a _text editor_ (like Visual Studio Code) and inspect. Often what happens is the data in fields contain commas and it confuses the importer.

Comment: I've opened the file with a text editor and the content is separated by semicolons